# Unsigned character gotchas in C

Tags: c, internationalization, eof, unsigned-char

Most C compilers use signed characters. Most C libraries define EOF as -1.

Despite being a long-time C programmer I had never before put these two facts together and so in the interest of robust and international software I would ask for a bit of help in spelling out the implications.

Here is what I have discovered thus far:

- fgetc() and friends cast to unsigned characters before returning as int to avoid clashing with EOF.
- Therefore care needs to be taken with the results, e.g. `getchar() == (unsigned char) 'µ'`.
- <strike>Theoretically I believe that not even the basic character set is guaranteed to be positive.</strike>
- The `<ctype.h>` functions are designed to handle EOF and expected unsigned characters. Any other negative input may cause out-of-bounds addressing.
- Most functions taking character parameters as integers ignore EOF and will accept signed or unsigned characters interchangeably.
- String comparison (strcmp/strncmp/memcmp) compares unsigned character strings.
- It may not be impossible to discriminate EOF from a proper characters on systems where sizeof(int) = 1.
- The wide characters functions are not used for binary I/O and so WEOF is defined within the range of wchar_t.

Is this assessment correct and if so *what other gotchas did I miss?*

<sub>Full disclosure: I ran into an out-of-bounds indexing bug today when feeding non-ASCII characters to isspace() and the realization of the amount of lurking bugs in my old code both scared and annoyed me. Hence this frustrated question.</sub>

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit code; there are no "negative characters" unless you use a non-ASCII character set. And if you need to use more than ASCII with C, signed characters are the least of your problems.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Thankfully my need for internationalization has been slim so far, though I fear it may be growing. I do often need to pass through Latin-1 or UTF-8 strings as-is though (think simple parsers and the like.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic execution character set is guaranteed to be nonnegative - the precise wording in C99 is:

> If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a `char`
>   object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that paragraph (or perhaps I ought to buy myself a copy of the standard proper instead of relying on the drafts.)